# When I apply a certain CSS class in my ember app, the text disappears

Tags: css, ember.js, ember-cli

So I'm trying to integrate a template I purchased into a new ember app I am writing. The problem I am having is that the text is not being displayed on the page. When I debug using chrome dev tools or firebug, the elements are being included but not visible. If I live edit the elements to remove the 'section-wrapper' class the text is then visible, but it loses the formatting necessary. This only happens when I include the content via handlebars template. If I put the content in index.html all is well.

It works fine as static html here: http://static.rottengrapesyndicate.com/

But when I move the same content into application.hbs it has problems here: http://rottengrapesyndicate.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with help from the template author, I found that adding the following resolved my issue:

`.ember-view {
     height:100%;
}`

Answer (score 2):

It's not disappearing, it's positioned absolute and being displayed outside the viewable area.

Since your CSS is inline, here's the code for the "A Better Way..." container

```
<div class="content-wrapper clearfix wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s" style="position: absolute; visibility: visible; -webkit-animation: fadeInDown 0.3s; top: 0px;">
```

in `#main-content .section-wrapper .content-wrapper`, replace `bottom: 16%;` with the relevant margin as it's pushing the container outside `#main-content`.

Comment: It looks like one of the plugins is injecting that inline styling into the output as that's not how it's coded in either the static or the ember indexes. I've tried changing the bottom margin in several different ways but no change. It's weird because the output of the static and ember versions are identical but in the dynamic one it's being pushed off the page.